# vuejs 2 with SVG

Tags: svg, vue.js

Problem: I want to use 3 different range to adjust an SVG triangle and get the color that user input

here is the code pen link: https://codepen.io/ookangzheng/pen/MoEgME?editors=1011

```js
var getColor = document.getElementById("#inputColor").value;
new Vue({
  el: '#drawing',
  data: {
    color:"red",
    a: 50,
    b: 95,
    c: 5,
  },
  methods:{
    update: function(inputColor){
        
        //getColor.value="blue";
        this.color = inputColor;
        console.log("update pressed + inputColor");
        return this.a, this.b, this.c;
    },
    changeColor(){
        
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick for you:

```
<div id="drawing">
    <input v-model="a" type="range" /> A: {{a}} <br>
    <input v-model="b" type="range" /> B: {{b}}<br>
    <input v-model="c" type="range" /> C: {{c}}<br>
    <input type="text" v-model="color" id="inputColor"/>
    <svg class="svg-triangle" width='100' height='100'>
    <path :d="result" v-bind:class="color"/>
  </svg>
    <p>
        <ul>
            <li>red</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>green</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <button v-on:click="update">update</button>
  </div>
```

Your javascript code can be simplified to:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#drawing',
  data: {
    color:"red",
    a: 50,
    b: 95,
    c: 5,
    result: ''
  },
  methods:{
    update: function(){
        this.result = `M ${a}, 6 ${b}, 97.5 ${c}, 97.5 z`
    }
  }   
})
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsbin.com/mevehipoce/edit?html,js,output